# crystal reports location outside exe

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I wanted the user to have freedom to change the layout of crystal reports at runtime...but as I didnt get any solution for this. I want to place the crystal reports outside the exe file so that user can open crystal reports and edit it..but HOw to access crystal reports outside exe.

Im using crystal report with typed dataset. In windows app vb.net 2008 and mssql 2005

```
     Dim sql1 As String = "select company_name,pobox,city,address,telephone,fax,website,email,logo,sign,supplier_name,date,created_by,request_id,request_no from company,request where request_id ='" + txtRequestId.Text + "'"
        Dim sql2 As String = "select no,item_name,group_name,description,qty,request_id from request_item where request_id ='" + txtRequestId.Text + "'"

        Dim dbConn As SqlConnection = cl.sqlConn()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim ds As New dsRequest()

        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql1, dbConn)
         da.Fill(ds, "details")

        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql2, dbConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "items")

        Dim oRpt As New rptRequest
        oRpt.SetDataSource(ds)
```

I could use rptRequest before because before it was inside project but now I have placed it outside..so how to access rptRequest.rpt. Please help as Idnt know much about rptRequest.
If anyone knows about runtime layout designer for cyrstal reports or any other reporting please let me know. Im ready to pay money also.Please help.

Comment: Is there no one who knowws about reporting in stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recognise the method you're using above but I would use the following method to load the report:

```
Dim reportPath as String = "C:\Report.rpt"
Dim ReportDoc As ReportDocument = new ReportDocument()
ReportDoc.Load(reportPath)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bendataclear. Atleast some1 replied. Im creating an object of rptRequest: Dim oRpt As New rptRequest .Let me try your suggestion

Comment: I'm not familiar with rptRequest, is this a class you've added yourself?

Comment: no it is crystalReport Name not any function or class..sorry for the confusion

Comment: bendataclear : do you know to use vc++ project in vb.net windows app.I got runtime layout designer in vc++ but dont know how to use it in vb.net windows app. Can you help?

Comment: You should be able to import the vc++ project into your olution although I've never tried this with c++ only c#/vb.net. Do you have the source or is it compiled?

Comment: bendataclear : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11873/Integrate-Crystal-Reports-Runtime-Designer-Viewer .this is in vc++ I want to use this functionallity in my vb.net windows app .I would be really greatfull if you can help me on this.